# New ProLiant ML10 v2 won't power on

Tags: hardware, hp-proliant, hpe

I just unpacked a brand new HP (HPE now I guess) ProLiant ML10 v2 Tower Server System i3-4150 3.5 GHz. It responded as expected to a press and release of the power-on button once, but the system became unresponsive after I waited for it to complete its Early Initialization Sequence (it got as far as 20%) for 20 minutes. Now it will not respond to a press and release (nor press and hold) of the power-on button at all.

I have the [User Guide](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/action.process/public/psi/manualsDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=7796450&javax.portlet.action=true&spf_p.tpst=psiContentDisplay&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.prp_psiContentDisplay=wsrp-interactionState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c04622279%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) and Troubleshooting Guide Volumes [1](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c04444029) and [2](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c04443553). None of these documents address this problem.

The Front panel LEDs and buttons table from the User Guide shows:
[image: ProLiant ML10 v2 Front Panel LEDs and Buttons]

My server LEDs are currently all dark except the Power On/Standby button and system power LED which is flashing green at 1 Hz. It's been in this condition for more than 2 hours while I've tried to find solutions to this problem using documentation and web searches. The first time I powered it on, this LED was also flashing and it became solid green after I pressed and released the button as the server seemed to boot up normally sending typical bootup sequence output text to the attached display. So based on my experience thus far, the "Flashing green (1 Hz/cycle per sec) = Performing power on sequence" line of this table seems to be misleading.

I'd call HPE except that it's a Saturday and I don't have a service contract. Can anyone offer insight on what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: New HPE servers don't come with even a basic service/support contract by default?

Comment: No. User guide offers links to details for purchasing one, but nothing by default.

Comment: The HP system you mention has a 1-year support agreement. You can call for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HP system has manufacturer support for one year from purchase date. You could also contact the party that sold you the system: e.g. vendor support.

You can connect to the ILO4 interface and read the contents of the server IML log. This will tell you what the server thinks is wrong.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion to look at the ILO4 interface. ILO is new to me, but I read a little about it. Looks like I would need an IP address to connect to the server's ILO4 interface, right? I looked at my network map and the server is not present on the network. Wouldn't the server need to be booted up to appear on the network? Or is the ILO4 interface like a separate device in the server case that is running even when the main device is down?

Comment: The ILO is shared with your main ethernet interface. It defaults to DHCP. The login/password are printed on a label attached to the server. You can modify its configuration from the server BIOS as well.

Comment: With HPE chat-based support (on a Saturday no less! Kudos to HPE on that), I learned that I had two problems: (1) I had to unplug the machine from AC power, press and hold power button for 10 seconds, then release power button, replug machine into AC, and then the power button worked as expected again; (2) in addition to one HPE DIMM installed, I also had 3 non-HPE DIMMs installed (although non-HPE DIMMs were cheaper, removing them eliminated the machine's inability to progress past the early initialization sequence. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: You had cheap incompatible RAM in the server?!?

Comment: It met the technical specifications of the server. It just wasn't made by HPE. You think this is a bad idea? I've never had problems doing this before with myriad other servers.

Comment: HPE tech support set me straight on the above point. non-HPE components of any kind are not allowed and may cause malfunction in known ways (such as that which I encountered). That's a real surprise to me. I knew Dell did this, but this is my first HPE server. Are there any server manufacturers who allow the use of commodity components like RAM and HDD and optical drives? That's another question I know. So lesson learned for me. Thanks for all the thoughts. Educational experience for me.